# How to set up a child or grandchild state as the default index state with ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular with ui-router. What I'd like to do is when a user browse to links such as:

```
/
/contacts
/contacts/:id
```

they all default display the same content as the link **/contacts/:id** with a default :id, and the url remains unchanged (not being changed to **/contacts/:id**).

There is a FAQ on ui-router wiki about this, but it doesn't demo how to init with grandchild or even deeper descendant states.

> [How to: Set up a default/index child state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state)

I've tried several different state settings with no avail. Am I doing it wrong? Here's the sample page:

> [ui-router-test](http://begeeben.github.io/playground/ui-router)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem with .when(). Sample:
    [ui-router-test](http://begeeben.github.io/playground/ui-router).

```
$urlRouterProvider
    .when('/', ['$state', function ($state) {
        $state.transitionTo('contacts.detail', {contactId: 1}, {location: false});
    }])
    .when('/contacts', ['$state', function ($state) {
        $state.transitionTo('contacts.detail', {contactId: 1}, {location: false});
    }])
    .otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
.state("home", {
    url: "/"
})
.state('contacts', {
    url: '/contacts',
    template: 'Contacts: <div ui-view></div>'
})
.state('contacts.detail', {
    url: '/:contactId',
    template: '<p class="lead">Contact ID is {{$stateParams.contactId}}</p>'
});
```